# Push dates of commits in github

Tags: git, github

Is it possible to see commits push dates in github? I tried this command 
`git reflog --date=local origin/master`, it does what I need if it is used in source repository but it doesn't show anything in cloned repository. Basically I need a way to show that I was the first to push the code I have written in github to mitigate situations when a scammer copies the code from my public repository and falsely claims ownership over it, however unlikely that might be. The commit dates themselves can't be used for this because they are local and can be tampered with in theory.

Comment: Please notice that git and github aren’t the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can see from GitHub is whatever the folks who run GitHub choose to give you.  [GitHub Enterprise does offer push log information](https://help.github.com/enterprise/2.12/admin/articles/viewing-push-logs/), and [plain GitHub offers an audit log](https://help.github.com/articles/reviewing-the-audit-log-for-your-organization/).

> I tried [using] `git reflog` ...

That just shows you local reflog time stamps, generated by *your own* Git.  So that won't help much.

> The commit dates themselves can't be used for this because they are local and can be tampered with in theory.

Your concern is valid, but I think you are looking at this from the wrong angle.  Changing the commit's date changes the commit.  It's no longer the same commit.  You have, instead, a new and *different* commit, with a different hash ID.<sup>1</sup>  The way this becomes an issue is that you make your commit, with your tree and metadata, and then competitor X can make his own (different) commit with your tree and his metadata, using arbitrary metadata, including an earlier timestamp.

Relying on GitHub to provide the time-stamps, though, is not going to help as much as you might like, I think.  What you need is something that is actually enforceable in a legal sense, and—at least today—that's copyright law, which is recognized in a statistically significant portion of the world.  The rules for using copyright law are not really in scope here on StackOverflow, though; [law.stackexchange.com](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/copyright) seems a much better fit.

---

<sup>1</sup>It's true that *in theory* you could break SHA-1 and come up with a new, consistent, valid commit with an adjusted date and yet the same hash ID.  But [the technique used for making two PDF files with the same hash ID](https://shattered.it/) must be modified to apply to commits, and will leave ridiculously-obvious fingerprints.